# Searching A Gridview With A DataTable Datasource

Tags: asp.net, search, gridview, datatable

I have a gridview that gets its data from a webservice.

This comes into the application in a dataset.

```
   Me.GvStreets.DataSource = TheWebServiceSearch.AddressDataTable
   Me.GvStreets.DataBind()
```

Once in the grid view how do I search the contents of this dataset.

Do I have to add it to some sort of datasource control like an XML datasource?

Thanks

What I ended up doing was this...

```
  Dim StreetDataTable As DataTable = Session("StreetData")
   Dim Name As String = StreetDataTable.Columns(0).ColumnName

   Dim FilteredResults As New DataTable
   FilteredResults = StreetDataTable.Clone()

   Dim DataRows() As DataRow
   DataRows = StreetDataTable.Select("street LIKE '%" & Me.txtStreet.Text & _


                         "%'", "Street ASC")
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To DataRows.GetUpperBound(0)

        FilteredResults.ImportRow(DataRows(i))

    Next i

    Me.GvStreets.DataSource = FilteredResults
    Me.GvStreets.DataBind()
```

I had to get the results and clone the data table to get the schema. Then I did the select from the original datatable. I looped through the results and added them to the cloned data table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you would search your data source directly, so in your case since TheWebServiceSearch.AddressDataTable is a DataTable, you can do the following:

```
DataTable data = TheWebServiceSearch.AddressDataTable;
DataRow[] foundRows = data.Select("city = 'NY'", "zip ASC");
```

You can check out the complete list of DataTable.Select overloads [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx)

---

Oh okay, now I see what you need. I thought you wanted something else. Anyways for your purpose you should use DataView object (which is also bindable). Here's an example:

```
Dim StreetDataTable As DataTable = Session("StreetData")
Dim Name As String = StreetDataTable.Columns(0).ColumnName
StreetDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "street LIKE '%" & Me.txtStreet.Text & "%'"
StreetDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "Street ASC"

Me.GvStreets.DataSource = StreetDataTable.DefaultView
Me.GvStreets.DataBind()
```

Take a look at [complete specification of DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx).

Comment: And what if I was to search on multiple columns and need wild cards is this possible?

Comment: @Paul - check out this page for an in-depth explanation of the data.Select() expression arguments: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx